# How to use types generated by gdbus-codegen?

Tags: c++, c, gio, gdbus

I am implementing a dbus server, and to simplify things, I decided to use `gdbus-codegen`.

[This hello world example](https://fatminmin.com/blog/dbus-gdbus-hello-world.html) and [it's repository](https://github.com/chiehmin/gdbus_test) are going to generate header and source files. Then it do this to connect the signal to the function:

```
g_signal_connect (interface, 
                  "handle-hello-world", 
                  G_CALLBACK (on_handle_hello_world), NULL);
```

My questions are next:

- what is the function `GType min_min_bus_gdbus_get_type (void)` supposed to do? It is declared, but not defined in generated files.
- instead of connecting signal to a callback function (as described above), can I somehow use the `struct MinMinBusGDBUSIface`, declared in the generated header?

---

Any example that I found on the net, are having these two things (`*_get_type (void)` function declaration, and `struct *Iface` declared in the generated header. How to use them?

Comment: Yes, C is a different language to C++. Do you want answers in C *or* C++?

Comment: @Toby I know they are different, but the answer should be the same for both C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

After playing with the example, finally I figured out the answers, and how to gain access to the interface structure, and how to set it. This is nowhere to be found, and is not documented anywhere.

---

After looking into the generated source file, the function `GType min_min_bus_gdbus_get_type (void)` may be defined in a huge macro garble, but I am not sure of it's functionality, and how to use it.

---

There is a way to access the `struct MinMinBusGDBUSIface` by use of the `MIN_MIN_BUS_GDBUS_GET_IFACE` macro (again in the generated header).

To set the function callback, this line in the example:

```
g_signal_connect (interface, 
                  "handle-hello-world", 
                  G_CALLBACK (on_handle_hello_world), NULL);
```

can be replaced by:

```
MinMinBusGDBUSIface* iface = MIN_MIN_BUS_GDBUS_GET_IFACE(interface);
iface->handle_hello_world = &on_handle_hello_world;
```

and the callback has to be modified to has the same signature as the function callback:

```
static gboolean
on_handle_hello_world (MinMinBusGDBUS *interface, 
                       GDBusMethodInvocation *invocation,
                       const gchar *greeting)
```

Comment: “This is nowhere to be found, and is not documented anywhere.” It _is_ documented: the GObject manual. This is a standard GObject type definition, and the assumption is that if you’re using `gdbus-codegen`, you have read about how to use GObject. Here’s the manual: https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/index.html

Comment: @PhilipWithnall Thanks. There is not even one example showing this. All are with "g_signal_connect"